# Why don't these AngularJS decorators not uglify properly?

Tags: angularjs

I'm using this fix I found to be able to use dynamically created forms and fields in AngularJS 1.2.27, but it won't uglify properly.  Saying it doesn't recognize or can't find a dependency when run after uglify, but the decorators are using array format.  Is there something else I'm missing?  It's the only file in my project that fails after uglify.

```
.config(function( $provide ) {

    $provide.decorator('ngModelDirective', ['$delegate', 
        function( $delegate ) {

            var ngModel = $delegate[0],
                controller = ngModel.controller;

            ngModel.controller = ['$scope', '$element', '$attrs', '$injector',
                function(scope, element, attrs, $injector) { 
                    var $interpolate = $injector.get('$interpolate');
                    attrs.$set('name', $interpolate(attrs.name || '')(scope));
                    $injector.invoke(controller, this, {
                        '$scope': scope,
                        '$element': element,
                        '$attrs': attrs
                    });
                }
            ];
            return $delegate;
    }]);

    $provide.decorator('formDirective', ['$delegate', 
        function( $delegate ) {

            var form = $delegate[0],
                controller = form.controller;

            form.controller = ['$scope', '$element', '$attrs', '$injector',
                function(scope, element, attrs, $injector) {
                    var $interpolate = $injector.get('$interpolate');
                    attrs.$set('name', $interpolate(attrs.name || attrs.ngForm || '')(scope));
                    $injector.invoke(controller, this, {
                        '$scope': scope,
                        '$element': element,
                        '$attrs': attrs
                    });
                }
            ];
            return $delegate;
    }]);
});
```

Is it the function params not having $? and if so can I just get rid of the $injector.invoke(controller, this... and change param names to reflect array format dependency injection variable names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you also need to give the variable names for dependency injection in array format for the `config` function for any type of uglification scenario:

```
.config([ '$provide', function( $provide ) {...}]);
```

Comment: Good call, I was too focused inside the .config on the $decorators